# How do I use 1D gradients to compute a 2D Sobel in OpenCV with a different vector norm?

Tags: python, opencv, derivative, sobel

OpenCV uses an implementation of a [Sobel operator defined here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#gacea54f142e81b6758cb6f375ce782c8d) ([details here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html)). In this implementation, the horizontal derivative is generated, then the vertical derivative is generated, then the gradient is computed as the L2 norm of the derivatives.

Let's say I wanted to use the L1 norm instead. In order to prove this out, I take an image and try to get the same result from OpenCV's `Sobel()` that I get from manually calculating the L2 norm of the gradients:

```py
import cv2


z_img = cv2.imread(".\\some_image.tif", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

z_px_rows = z_img.shape[0]
z_px_cols = z_img.shape[1]

print(f'Center pixel intensity (original): {z_img[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

gx = cv2.Sobel(z_img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0, ksize=13)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (gx): {gx[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

gy = cv2.Sobel(z_img, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1, ksize=13)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (gy): {gy[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

mag, _ = cv2.cartToPolar(gx, gy)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (homebrew sobel): {mag[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

native_sobel = cv2.Sobel(z_img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 1, ksize=13)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (native sobel): {native_sobel[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')
```

Here I'm using a 32-bit float image where the minimum is 0.0 and the maximum is around 600.0. The output of this is:

```
Center pixel intensity (original): 537.156982421875
Center pixel intensity (gx): -220087.90625
Center pixel intensity (gy): 350005.25
Center pixel intensity (homebrew sobel): 413451.78125
Center pixel intensity (native sobel): 16357.7548828125
```

Obviously, something is way off. I would expect those last two values to be the same (not ***exactly*** the same, but definitely close). I tried normalizing the pixels in the image to the range [0, 1], which didn't help. I tried converting the images to 8-bit unsigned, which also didn't help. What have I misunderstood about the implementation that would account for this discrepancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing "apples" to "oranges".

In Python/OpenCV, cv2.Sobel() computes either the X directional derivative or the Y directional derivative or a mixed derivative as follows:

[image]

This is not the same as the magnitude of the gradient:

[image]

where `x(I) = X` directional derivative from the Sobel,
`y(I) = Y` directional derivative from the Sobel with
`I` = src and magnitude = dst

If you want the L1 norm, then in place of the square root magnitude above, use

```
magnitude(I) = |x(I)| + |y(I)|
```

where `x(I) = X` directional derivative and `y(I) = Y` directional derivative (from Sobel) and `I` = src and magnitude = dot

Comment: I think my question is more like, if I have sobel(dx=1, dy=0) and sobel(dx=0, dy=1), can those images/matrices be used to calculate the output of sobel(dx=1, dy=1)? If so, how? My understanding of the algorithm from the links I posted is that it should just be the magnitude, but that's obviously wrong. I just don't understand WHY it's wrong.

Comment: No, unfortunately, as in my answer, the formula in the documentation shows that the result of sobel(dx=1, dy=1) is not the magnitude but a mixed derivative. If you want the magnitude (to compare to other tools), then you need to compute it yourself from the X and Y derivatives, namely, sobel(dx=1, dy=0) and sobel(dx=0, dy=1). You cannot get the magnitude directly from sobel(dx=1, dy=1).

Comment: According to Wikipedia at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative, the mixed derivative is the cross partial derivatives.  For example for second order, that would be gradient_x of gradient_y of image  or gradient_y of gradient_x of image. So I believe that means: sobel(sobel(image, dx=1, dy=1), dx=0, dy=1)

Comment: Ah, thank you, I see at least part of what I've misunderstood. Can you help me understand how that's possible if the result of sobel(dx=1, dy=1) is a 2D array of scalars? If it's NOT a magnitude, doesn't that mean it would have to be a 2D array of vectors? I think this is why I assumed that sobel() would return a magnitude for each pixel (which is how I interpret the documentation).

Comment: It is a mixed derivative of scalars. I do not think it is a vector. If it were a vector, then you would get two component results, one for x and one for y.  But cv2.Sobel returns only one scalar image. It is the x_gradient of the y_gradient of the image (or equally the y_gradient of  the x_gradient of the image).

Comment: See for example https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/partial-derivative-and-gradient-articles/a/second-partial-derivatives

Comment: Try matrix multiplying the x and y kernels and then applying that to the image. Does that match sobel with both x and y specified?

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75241333/3684433) from @fmw42 as correct, but I want to add more context.

The direct answer to my question is that I found the documentation misleading. The "Formulation" section in [this link](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/d2c/tutorial_sobel_derivatives.html) implied to me that the `cv2.Sobel()` method does the convolutions with the x and y kernels, and then returns the magnitude (L2 norm) of those derivatives.

The mistake that @fmw42 pointed out to me, and which I then verified, was that `cv2.Sobel()` ***does not*** calculate the magnitude for you. It only does the convolution using the Sobel kernels. You can verify by looking at the output of this code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


z_img = cv2.imread(".\\some_image.tif", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

z_px_rows = z_img.shape[0]
z_px_cols = z_img.shape[1]

kernel_x = np.array([[-1, 0, 1],
                     [-2, 0, 2],
                     [-1, 0, 1]])

kernel_y = np.array([[-1, -2, -1],
                     [ 0,  0,  0],
                     [ 1,  2,  1]])
  
gx = cv2.filter2D(src=z_img, ddepth=-1, kernel=kernel_x)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (gx): {gx[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

native_sobel_x = cv2.Sobel(z_img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0, ksize=3)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (native sobel x): {native_sobel_x[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

gy = cv2.filter2D(src=z_img, ddepth=-1, kernel=kernel_y)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (gy): {gy[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

native_sobel_y = cv2.Sobel(z_img, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1, ksize=3)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (native sobel y): {native_sobel_y[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

# Now take gx and convolve using the y kernel
mixed = cv2.filter2D(src=gx, ddepth=-1, kernel=kernel_y)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (mixed): {mixed[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

# And compare to calling Sobel(dy=1) on the output of Sobel(dx=1)
native_sobel_mixed = cv2.Sobel(native_sobel_x, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1, ksize=3)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (native sobel mixed): {native_sobel_mixed[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

native_sobel_both = cv2.Sobel(z_img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 1, ksize=3)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (native sobel): {native_sobel_both[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')
```

This will produce intensities of the center pixel as follows:

| Description | Intensity of center pixel |
| --- | --- |
| Manual convolution in x | -0.4061279296875 |
| `cv2.Sobel(dx=1, dy=0)` | -0.4061279296875 |
| Manual convolution in y | 0.41986083984375 |
| `cv2.Sobel(dx=0, dy=1)` | 0.419921875 |
| Manual convolution in x, then y | 1.994873046875 |
| `cv2.Sobel()` in x, then y | 1.9949951171875 |
| `cv2.Sobel(dx=1, dy=1)` | 0.2659912109375 |

What remains a mystery to me is why calling `cv2.Sobel(dx=1, dy=1)` generates a different result from calling `cv2.Sobel(dx=1)` on the original image and then calling `cv2.Sobel(dy=1)` on the result of the first call (the last three rows). That seems like a different question, though.

Comment: Try matrix multiplying the x and y kernels and then applying that to the image. Does that match sobel with both x and y specified?

Answer (score 0):

You question why the mixed filter2D gradient is not the same as the mixed sobel gradient with kernel dx=1 and dy=1. You have a couple of issues. 1) You did not ensure that your filter2D outputs were floats. 2) The answer is to do multiplication (element wise) between the two kernels first, then do the convolution with filter_2D (rather than successive convolutions). Note that it is element-wise multiplication rather than matrix multiplication. To show that, see the following script and results.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


z_img = cv2.imread("lena_gray.png")

z_px_rows = z_img.shape[0]
z_px_cols = z_img.shape[1]

kernel_x = np.array([[-1, 0, 1],
                     [-2, 0, 2],
                     [-1, 0, 1]])

kernel_y = np.array([[-1, -2, -1],
                     [ 0,  0,  0],
                     [ 1,  2,  1]])
# matrix multiply            
kernel_xy1 = np.matmul(kernel_x,kernel_y)
kernel_xy2 = np.matmul(kernel_x,kernel_y)
# element-wise multiply
kernel_xy3 = cv2.multiply(kernel_x,kernel_y)
kernel_xy4 = cv2.multiply(kernel_y,kernel_x)

print('')
print("kernel_xy1:\n", kernel_xy1)
print('')
print("kernel_xy2:\n", kernel_xy1)
print('')
print("kernel_xy3:\n", kernel_xy1)
print('')
print("kernel_xy4:\n", kernel_xy1)
print('')
  
gx = cv2.filter2D(src=z_img, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, kernel=kernel_x)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (gx): {gx[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

native_sobel_x = cv2.Sobel(z_img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 0, ksize=3)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (native sobel x): {native_sobel_x[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

gy = cv2.filter2D(src=z_img, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, kernel=kernel_y)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (gy): {gy[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

native_sobel_y = cv2.Sobel(z_img, cv2.CV_32F, 0, 1, ksize=3)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (native sobel y): {native_sobel_y[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

mixed1 = cv2.filter2D(src=z_img, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, kernel=kernel_xy1)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (mixed1 - matrix multiply): {mixed1[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

mixed2 = cv2.filter2D(src=z_img, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, kernel=kernel_xy2)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (mixed2 - matrix multiply): {mixed2[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

mixed3 = cv2.filter2D(src=z_img, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, kernel=kernel_xy3)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (mixed3 - element-wise multiply): {mixed3[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

mixed4 = cv2.filter2D(src=z_img, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, kernel=kernel_xy4)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (mixed4 - element-wise multiply): {mixed4[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')

native_sobel_xy = cv2.Sobel(z_img, cv2.CV_32F, 1, 1, ksize=3)
print(f'Center pixel intensity (native sobel xy): {native_sobel_xy[z_px_rows // 2, z_px_cols // 2]}')
```

Results:

```
kernel_xy1:
 [[2 4 2]
 [4 8 4]
 [2 4 2]]

kernel_xy2:
 [[2 4 2]
 [4 8 4]
 [2 4 2]]

kernel_xy3:
 [[2 4 2]
 [4 8 4]
 [2 4 2]]

kernel_xy4:
 [[2 4 2]
 [4 8 4]
 [2 4 2]]

Center pixel intensity (gx): [6. 6. 6.]
Center pixel intensity (native sobel x): [6. 6. 6.]
Center pixel intensity (gy): [-184. -184. -184.]
Center pixel intensity (native sobel y): [-184. -184. -184.]
Center pixel intensity (mixed1 - matrix multiply): [2580. 2580. 2580.]
Center pixel intensity (mixed2 - matrix multiply): [2580. 2580. 2580.]
Center pixel intensity (mixed3 - element-wise multiply): [-28. -28. -28.]
Center pixel intensity (mixed4 - element-wise multiply): [-28. -28. -28.]
Center pixel intensity (native sobel xy): [-28. -28. -28.]
```

Comment: Thank you for this example! A couple fixes: 1.) the "matrix multiply" lines are identical (`kernel_xy1` and `kernel_xy2`). 2.) the kernel prints are all the same (they're all `kernel_xy1`). 3.) I didn't provide my sample image, but it's 32-bit floating point, so using `ddepth=-1` worked fine in my case, but in general, good point.

Comment: When I tried your code on my image with ddepth=-1 or a uint8 image, it got wrong values (0s replaced all negative results). When I changed it to cv2.CV_32F floats, I got correct negative values.